# std::map with value of struct error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I use Visual Studio Express 2013 and I try to run this code:

```
struct opcode {
    int length; 
};

std::map<int, struct opcode> opcodes;

opcodes[0x20] = {
    3
};
```

I get this error:
`error C2040: 'opcodes' : 'int [32]' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::map<int,opcode,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'`

And when I hover over `opcodes` I get this `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`.

**SOLUTION**

The problem of mine was that I have put the statement outside the function.

Comment: You're missing the [tag:visual-studio], [tag:visual-studio-express] and [tag:visual-studio-2013] tags for this question. :)

Comment: @jotik I'm not sure how much it matters.  This is mostly a straight C++ question.

Comment: I have updated question tags. It seems really a visual studio related issue as from command line it's all good.
@jotik, I have done it and no warnings given.

Comment: This is a long shot, but try `std::map<int, opcode> opcodes;` without the `struct` keyword. Maybe this confuses the compiler.

Comment: @jotik, no luck without `struct` keyword.

Comment: In C++ languge statements have to reside inside functions. This `opcodes[0x20] = { 3 };` is a statement. You cannot just throw it into a file without declaring a function.

Comment: @AndreyT, please can you elaborate a little bit more ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ language statements - i.e. "the actual code" - have to reside inside functions. This

```
opcodes[0x20] = {
    3
};
```

is a statement. You cannot just throw it into a file without declaring a function. You cannot just write C++ code (i.e. statements) in the middle of the file.

All you can do in the "whitespace" between function is write *declarations*. So, you statement above was interpreted by the compiler as a declaration. Hence the strange error messages from the compiler.

If you intended this to be a statement, it should have looked as follows (for example)

```
int main()
{
  opcodes[0x20] = { 3 };    
}
```

However, you could achieve the same effect without a function by using an *initializer*, which is a part of declaration

```
std::map<int, struct opcode> opcodes = { { 0x20, { 3 } } };
```

Comment: You've opened my eyes! Thanks!

Comment: @lukas.pukenis Maybe you want `std::map<int, opcodes> opcodes = {{0x20, {3}}};`

Comment: My problem was that I have put this outside the `main()` function(or any other) and as @AndreyT stated, statements cannot live alone

Comment: @lukas.pukenis I think you can still use `std::map<int, opcodes> opcodes{{0x20, {3}}};` in namespace scope because it is a definition.